# Force reload of Tiles in Layer

Tags: openlayers

I want to display an indoor map. My problem is that when I change to another floor (the URL changes) the tiles are not refetched. The following code is used:

```
var indoorSource = new ol.source.XYZ({
    crossOrigin: null,
    tileUrlFunction: parseUrl,
    maxZoom: 45
});
var indoorLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: indoorSource
});
```

The parseUrl function is the following:

```
var parseUrl = function (tileCoords, pixelRatio, projection) {
    var url = 'http://127.0.0.1/tiles/{z}/{level}/{x}/{y}';
    var innerMap = LocalUserData.currentInnerMap();

    url = url.replace('{level}', innerMap.level || 0);
    url = url.replace('{z}', tileCoords.z || 0);
    url = url.replace('{x}', tileCoords.x || 0);
    url = url.replace('{y}', tileCoords.y || 0);
    return url;
};
```

Is there a way to force a reload of the tiles?

Comment: I have found that reprojection makes none of the above options work on XYZ

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 ways to avoid getting cached data.

1. Add additional parameter in your request and make it's value to `Math.random()` , so every time browser will deal with this request as new and will fetch it from source and will not depend on cache.
   for example:

> ```
> var mr = Math.random();  
> var url = 'http://127.0.0.1/tiles/{z}/{level}/{x}/{y}&AutoKey=' + mr ;
> ```

2. Another way that you use POST in your request instead of GET, indeed you are forcing the browser to get data from server.

I have already went through a similar issue specially with IE but my problem was fetching cached vector data while they have been changed already.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem and finally I could fix it.
You can see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255814/openlayers-4-force-refresh-tiles-in-ol-source-vectortile-on-interval/)

Use this refresh function whenever you need:

```
function refresh() {
    var source = layer.getSource();
    source.tileCache.expireCache({});
    source.tileCache.clear();
    source.refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dispatching a change event from your source notifies the map something has changed and should redraw the layer.

```
indoorSource.dispatchChangeEvent()
```

http://ol3js.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.source.XYZ.html#dispatchChangeEvent

Comment: I tried that but it does not work. Probably because the XYZ source uses an internal cache which uses x, y, z parameters for equality, those don't change so the tiles are not reloaded. Maybe I have to provide my own Tile Source implementation but would be glad if there is a simpler solution.

Comment: I guess `source.setTileUrlFunction` may have work, as it clears the cache, but seems not to be exported ( https://github.com/tonio/ol3/blob/default_editing_style/src/ol/source/tileimagesource.js#L146 )

Comment: That works. I'm using the following the following code to reload the tiles: var refreshTiles = function () {
                indoorSource.setTileUrlFunction(parseUrl);
            };

Comment: For me, for a local xyz tile layer, this method of calling setTileUrlFunction() on the layer's source is the only thing that appears to work to cause openlayers to re-query all the layer's tiles.

Comment: Update: Now that I'm using OpenLayers 6, the solution by @Ahmad Azimi works for me.